# Bootstrap timepicker not working on dynamic textbox generated on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There was no problem when the timepicker loaded in page-load,

```
<script src="~/Contents/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

 <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
     <input id="FlightArrivalTimepicker0" name="" type="text" class="form-control iconnn-time-new time1">
           </div>
        <script>  $('#FlightArrivalTimepicker0').timepicker();</script>
```

When i am trying to load this timepicker in a button click , there encountering an error like 'method undefined' please help me to solve this issue.

```
 var arrivalId = "#FlightArrivalTimepicker2";
 var newItem = ('<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <label class="control-label">Arrival </label> <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"> <input id="FlightArrivalTimepicker2" name="" type="text" class="form-control iconnn-time-new time1">   <script> $(' + arrivalId + ').timepicker();<\/script> </div></div>');
                $("#FlightDetails").append(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include your script-tag inside your newItem definition. Move it out and exectute the call after you append the item to the dom

```
var arrivalId = "#FlightArrivalTimepicker2";
     var newItem = ('<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <label class="control-label">Arrival </label> <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"> <input id="FlightArrivalTimepicker2" name="" type="text" class="form-control iconnn-time-new time1"></div></div>');
                    $("#FlightDetails").append(newItem);
    $(arrivalId).timepicker(); //don't put this inline - and DON'T QUOTE your variable!!
```

Here's a link to a working fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/4drtbqnc/

Comment: $(' + arrivalId + ').timepicker(); when using this code to load timepicker ,its not working and returns same error

Comment: The problem were the quotes around arrivalId - that was just silly. - Once you remove them this will work just fine.

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Might need an update.

Answer (score 1):

Please Modify the code

```
var arrivalId = "#FlightArrivalTimepicker2";
var newItem = ('<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <label class="control-label">Arrival </label> <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"> <input id="FlightArrivalTimepicker2" name="" type="text" class="form-control iconnn-time-new time1">   <script> $(' + arrivalId + ').timepicker();<\/script> </div></div>');
            $("#FlightDetails").append(newItem);
```

To

```
var newItem = ('<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <label class="control-label">Arrival </label> <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"> <input id="FlightArrivalTimepicker2" name="" type="text" class="form-control iconnn-time-new time1 show-timepicker"></div></div>');
$(newItem).appendTo("#FlightArrivalTimepicker2");
```

And

```
<script>  $('#FlightArrivalTimepicker0').timepicker();</script>
```

To

```
<script>  $('.show-timepicker').timepicker();</script>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: `.bootstrap-timepicker` is a `div` element

Comment: yes, it was my mistake and now I have modified the code, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrivalId = "#FlightArrivalTimepicker2";
var newItem = ('<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <label class="control-label">Arrival </label> <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"> <input id="'+arrivalId+'" name="" type="text" class="form-control iconnn-time-new time1"></div></div>');
$("#FlightDetails").append(newItem);
$(' + arrivalId + ').timepicker(); // init timepicker
```